# BizTalk 2013 fails to import bindings on a VM

Tags: biztalk, biztalk-2013

I'm getting an error when importing bindings into a BizTalk Server 2013 running on a VM (VMWare).
My physical server has never shown this error and I've had this error plenty times to know it's caused by a binding file error.
Size of the file also doesn't matter.
This happens intermittent and often closing the Admin console or logging off the VM and back on will help. But right now none of these are helping.
I'm wondering if anyone has a solution for this:

===================================

Failed to update binding information. (mscorlib)

===================================

The connection was not closed. The connection's current state is open. (Microsoft.BizTalk.ExplorerOM)

---

Program Location:

at Microsoft.BizTalk.ExplorerOM.BtsCatalogExplorer.SaveChangesWithTransaction(Object transactionObj)
   at Microsoft.BizTalk.Deployment.Binding.BindingInfo.UpdateParties(String connectionString, Boolean overwrite)
   at Microsoft.BizTalk.Deployment.Binding.BindingInfo.Update(SqlConnection sqlConnection, BindingParameters bindingParameters, String applicationName)

Comment: Looking at the Program Location is seems to be having some problems with updating the parties.  Is there any party information in your bindings?

Comment: <PartyCollection xsi:nil="true" />

Comment: Does it fail with the same Program Location each time, or at different points?  Are there any errors in the Application Windows Logs?

Comment: I removed the PartyCollection element from the bindings file completely and now I get a different error:  Microsoft.BizTalk.ExplorerOM.BtsCatalogExplorer.SaveChangesWithTransaction(Object transactionObj)
   at Microsoft.BizTalk.ExplorerOM.BtsCatalogExplorer.SaveChanges()
   at Microsoft.BizTalk.Deployment.Binding.BindingInfo.Update(SqlConnection sqlConnection, BindingParameters bindingParameters, String applicationName)

Comment: It might be time to rebuild that VM as it looks like there is something seriously wrong with it.   Have you tried deleting all the applications (apart from the Standard BizTalk ones)?

Comment: This happens on 5 different environments. Local, DEV, TST, UAT and PRD. These servers are also new and havent done much time.

Comment: Have you tried creating a new application in BizTalk, with just a couple of ports and exporting and importing that?  If that works you may have to simplify your binding file by removing some of the things that aren't really necessary for your deployment (e.g. the ModeRef nodes that just have the TrackedSchemas info) or to split it into multiple binding files, the first that creates the ports and then the second one to bind the orchestrations to those ports

Comment: I'm only importing a small portion of data. Files is stripped down to bare minimum already. I deleted the temp bindings files and I use a local BizTalk Admin console and somehow this has a higher success rate. Still not perfect.

Comment: For what it's worth to anyone who finds this in the future, it has happened to me a few times on a Win2k server with BT2016 (not even sure if it's a VM or not).  Closing BTAdmin and re-opening seems to the get-around, but quite annoying.